# Form error in a Django form with Bootstrap tagsinput plugin

Tags: html, django-forms, bootstrap-tags-input

I am using [Bootstrap/Tagsinput](https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput) for adding tags in a Django input form.

**Problem**

The first field is where I want the tags added and the second field is a simple text field. I am able to add the tags in the first field and a normal text in the second field. But, when I submit the form the input values get removed and am returned to the original form.  The django `form.errors` indicates that the second field is empty with a `This field is required` message even though I had entered a text! What am I missing?

[image]

**form.errors**

Is returning

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>experiments<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

**Here are the related files**

**tags_add.html**

I am using a custom html rather than the django's `forms.as_table`. All required `css` and `min.js` have been added in the `html` file.

```
<form id="defaultForm" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Tags:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <input type="text" name="tags" id="aa" class="form-control" value="" data-role="tagsinput" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Experiments:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <input type="text" name="tags" id="exp_id" class="form-control" value="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

**forms.py**

```
class TagsForm(ModelForm):
    tags = forms.CharField( widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'20', 'placeholder':'add tags'}), required=True )
    experiments = forms.CharField( widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'20', 'placeholder':'expid'}), required=True )
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TagsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Tags
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
def view_tags(request,formtype):
    form_type = formtype
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = form_type(request.POST or None)#, extra=extra_additives)
        if form.is_valid():
            instances = form.save(commit=False)
            temp_str= str(instances)
            print temp_str

            experiment_tags = temp_str
            return HttpResponse(experiment_tags)
        else:
            print "from view_tags {0}".format(form.errors)
            return HttpResponse(form.errors)
    else:
        form = TagsForm()
        return render(request, 'tags_add.html', {'form': form})
```

**models.py**

```
class Tags(models.Model):

    tags = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    experiments = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return ':'.join([self.tags, self.experiments])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working by adding the following to a `scripts` tag in the `html` file:

```
    $("input[name='tags']").tagsinput({
       confirmKeys:[13] //-- Only enter                                                                                   
     });
```